# iOS UIWebView with changing content size

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have a UIWebView which i've set the height of the WebView to

```
[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];
```

This works fine but on my webpage I have a menu which is expandable, so when the webpage is changing it's height the WebView doesn't increase/decrease it's size.

Any tips how I can make my UIWebView change height dynamically when the webpage is changing its size?

I would very much like to keep the UIWebView's size = webpage so I never have to scroll in the WebView.

Answer (score 2):

you can set sizeToFit property and again set Frame of UIWebView in webViewDidFinishLoad

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
       [detailsWebView sizeToFit];
       [detailsWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(detailsWebView.frame.origin.x, detailsWebView.frame.origin.y, 300.0, detailsWebView.frame.size.height)];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the contenSize of its scrollview:

```
detailsWebView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(detailsWebView.scrollView.contentSize.width,[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue]);
```

Comment: Where should I do that? The height changes after the webViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIWebView` property `scalesPageToFit = YES;`

Comment: The scalesPageToFit property won't change the height of the WebView which I am after, thanks anyway.