# UIWebView content width to custom size

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm displaying `Disqus` webpage in `UIWebView`. The page has its mobile version, which resizes it's view to the device. My problem is that `UIWebView` sets its content to device width, while my webView is about half od device width. Because of this, i can scroll my webview to right and left. I've already tried something like this: [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190504/ios-uiwebview-with-changing-content-size), setting `contentSize` etc but without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finished with following snippet, which completely works:

```
[aWebView loadRequest:aRequest progress:nil success:^NSString *(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSString *HTML) {
    NSMutableString *mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:HTML];
    NSRange range = [mutableString rangeOfString:@"width=device-width"]; // or whatever you have in response
    [mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"width=%d", (int)CGRectGetWidth(aWebView.frame)]];
    return mutableString;
} failure:nil];
```

Thanks for the idea to my colleague.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hack into the webview css and try change its width to your screen width / 2.